# Is depth registered image bigger than depth image in size?

Tags: ros, openni2-camera, openni.launch

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Is depth registered image bigger than depth image in size? I can't seem to find the answer in the internet.

I needed to know this for optimization in wireless image streaming. When I stream two openni2 cameras in one wifi network, sometimes it just drop frames. I was thinking if depth registered is larger than depth image, maybe I can just register the image in the base station, thus save bandwidth.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/187778/is-depth-registered-image-bigger-than-depth-image-in-size?/) by [Xegara](https://answers.ros.org/users/14401/xegara/) on ROS Answers with karma: 52 on 2014-07-24

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi there!

According to the headers of */camera/depth/image*:

```
$ rostopic echo -n 1 /camera/depth/image | head
header: 
  seq: 304
  stamp: 
    secs: 1406254046
    nsecs: 731604330
  frame_id: /camera_depth_optical_frame
height: 480
width: 640
encoding: 32FC1
is_bigendian: 0
```

and the headers of */camera/depth_registered/image_raw*:

```
$ rostopic echo -n 1 /camera/depth_registered/image_raw | head
header: 
  seq: 0
  stamp: 
    secs: 1406254097
    nsecs: 573718779
  frame_id: /camera_depth_optical_frame
height: 480
width: 640
encoding: 32FC1
is_bigendian: 0
```

They both are the same size: width, height and encoding are the same.

---

Originally posted by [Martin Peris](https://answers.ros.org/users/1108/martin-peris/) with karma: 5625 on 2014-07-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ROSkinect](https://answers.ros.org/users/17876/roskinect/) on 2014-07-25**:
how did you get that ? when I launch the command I get nothing !

**Comment by [Martin Peris](https://answers.ros.org/users/1108/martin-peris/) on 2014-07-25**:
you should be running "roslaunch openni_launch openni.launch" or "roslaunch openni2_launch openni2.launch" (depending on your RGBD sensor) on a separate terminal.